# How beneficial is IEEE student membership for a mathematics student?

Tags: ieee, professional-association

I am a Ph.D. mathematics student. I have no idea regarding IEEE student membership. IEEE has advertised many benefits and opportunities of it in their web pages.

Can you kindly explain how beneficial it may be for me? How may I use it for my academic and research works?

Comment: I'm not convinced IEEE membership is beneficial to anyone; unless your university does not have a subscription to the journals, and you need to buy them yourself.

Comment: The only benefit I have seen from being an IEEE member is the reduced registration cost for attending IEEE conferences.